# Javascript Underscore.js _.extend

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to learn some advanced javascript by trying to breakdown some code.  For this function I know what it does for the most part which is wrapping the function with logging capabilities so on future function calls it will log out to console.  I'm confused about the underscore.js _.extend - I know its suppose to copy over properties from source to destination.  However I don't see any difference between the original function and **obj[method]**.  I tried to examine the properties but nothing stands out?  Why do we need to call this anyways?  Thanks for any help!

```
function wrapWithLogger (msg, method, obj, color) {
    obj = obj || window;
    color = color || "blue";
    var fn = obj[method];

    obj[method] = function () {
        //console.log('Args: ', arguments);
        var strArgs = _.chain(arguments)
            .toArray(arguments)
            .map(function (arg) {
                if (_.isFunction(arg)) {
                    var fnName = arg.name || "fn";
                    return fnName + "() {...}";
                }
                else if (_.isObject(arg))
                    return "{...}";
                else
                    return JSON.stringify(arg);
            })
            .value()
            .join(", ");
        logWithColor(msg + "(" + strArgs + ")", color);
        return fn && fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };

  **.extend(obj[method], fn);**
}
```

Comment: I suppose if the original function had custom properties, this would preserve them onto the new wrapper function.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even work properly - it doesn't copy nonenumerable properties, most relevant of which would be the `.prototype`…